# Problems reading form data in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this **HTML** code that I am developing using **materialize CSS**. However, I cannot currently read the data from the input fields

```html
<form id="two_player">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Apelido do jogador 1" id="two_player_one" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="first_name">Jogador 1:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Apelido do jogador 2" id="two_player_two" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="player_two">Jogador 2:</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 1ª rodada" id="two_player_one_round_one" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate">
      <label for="player_one_round_one">Rodada 1:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Número de cartas da 1ª rodada" id="two_player_two_round_one" type="number" min="0" max="13" class="validate">
      <label for="player_two_round_one">Rodada 1:</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How do I read each input field with **JavaScript**?

Comment: `var value = document.getElementById('two_player_one').value;` etc.

Comment: Have you tried the regular JavaScript to read an HTML form field?  I don't see any JavaScript here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getElementById()` to find the element, and `.value` to expose its value.

```js
let two_player_one = document.getElementById('two_player_one').value;
let two_player_two = document.getElementById('two_player_two').value;
let two_player_one_round_one = document.getElementById('two_player_one_round_one').value;
let two_player_two_round_one = document.getElementById('two_player_two_round_one').value;
```

- MDN docs for `getElementById()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: The console doesn't show any value after I press the submit button. newgame.html:488 VM60:140 DomDistiller debug level: 0 If I only use the reference to the tag name it does the html code inside that input field.

Answer (score 1):

```
let val = document.getElementById('an input field ID').value;

    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++) {
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value);
    }
```

Basically something like this.
With the `for` loop, you loop through all the input elements and `console.log()` the value (or do whatever you want to with the value). The first one targets an element based on its `ID` and retrieves the value of it.

Comment: The console doesn't show any value after I press the submit button.
newgame.html:488 
VM60:140 DomDistiller debug level: 0

If I only use the reference to the tag name it does the html code inside that input field.

Comment: I assume your submit button is type submit? Change this to type=button

Comment: I did, still not getting any value... I removed the value attribute from the first console log and it shows the html element, however I cant get any values...

Comment: There you go :)